# React native getparam in url

Tags: react-native

I am trying to fetch data based on the ID supplied.

How can I use this
    this.props.navigation.getParam('prodId', 'Id')

at the end of this

```
return fetch(http://192.168.0 1/file.php?......)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
myFunction = () => {
   let id = this.props.navigation.getParam('prodId', 'Id')
   return fetch("http://192.168.0.1/file.php?id=" + id)
}
```

you can also just do it on one line:

```
return fetch("http://192.168.0.1/file.php?id=" + this.props.navigation.getParam('prodId', 'Id'))
```